# how to sort a file before starting a workflow of informatica using unix shell script?

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

how to sort a file before starting a workflow of Informatica using Unix shell script?
i have an file with 120 columns and thousands of records and i just want to sort this file using one column in Unix environment.

Comment: Please note this will create some I/O operations. If possible, I'd try to avoid it and do the operations within the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

ill explain you with example.
you have an file with 4 columns as given below.
 file name : Demo.txt

*id-first_name-last_name-salary*

```
 1-Alex-claire-10000
 2-jak-van-20000
 3-zander-ors-10000
 4-mack-glains-30000
 5-clans-argeds-50000
```

and you want to sort this file as first name ascending order

```
sort -t '-' -k2 Demo.txt
```

this command will sort the given file -k2 will indicate that column 2 i.e first name

Answer (score 0):

**You can also store this sorted file data or records in another file.**

```
 sort -t '-' -k2 Demo.txt > demo1.txt
```